# Sigmoid Activation Function (Output layer) Alternative

Tags: convolutional-neural-network, activation-function, generative-models, vae

I have a Convolutional-VAE architecture where the target images are in the range [0, 1], their pixel values. To synthesize/reconstruct images in this scale, I am using a sigmoid activation function in the output/last layer.

However, a problem with sigmoid activation function is that it is almost linear in the middle and then saturates towards the ends. This means that you need a large input to have a small/negligible output in these saturated zones. As a result, extreme values are usually not predicted by the network. For example, for a given target image, if the max value = 0.998, the max predicted value = 0.688, and therefore a good amount of difference is present. A similar situation can be seen for min values between true and predicted values.

Is there a way to avoid this sigmoid bias for the output layer? I am also assuming that because of this, the reconstruction loss also increases.

Comment: I doubt this is a source of large error in your model. Do your images have a lot of extreme values? You could always scale your input to be [0+e, 1-e] where you choose some e to stay away from the bounds. Then rescale the output.

Comment: @neuroguy123 any sample code?

Comment: Just x*0.9+0.05 if you wanted to squash to 0.05 to 0.95. See what I mean? You will lose some amount of granularity, but I doubt it matters for something like MNIST data.

Comment: Say x = -2.331, then your formula gives output as -2.16445. It's not scaling between (0.05, 0.95). There seems to be some confusion. Here 'x' is the raw score/logit before applying the scaling/activation function.